# how to remove *.pdb file of dll file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

for my website i have added the data access layer and business layer and add the dlls as reference.

but in the bin it is showing pdb file for both the dlls.

same time there are other third party tools.but they dont have the pdb file.

what is it used for.how can i remove the pdb file.

thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you have to deploy the .pdb file with compiling under release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608002/do-you-have-to-deploy-the-pdb-file-with-compiling-under-release)

Comment: The idea that .pdb files are only created in debug builds is false. Just switching to release won't remove the .pdb files.  You have to change an options setting.  See the responses to the linked question for details.

Answer (score 2):

The `.pdb` files are [Project Database files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx) that contain debugging information. You can remove them by going into settings and removing debug info from your configuration.

See [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608002/do-you-have-to-deploy-the-pdb-file-with-compiling-under-release) that [Jim Mischel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel) linked to in the comments. It provides good information about what these files are.

Answer (score 0):

*.pdb files are generated by dlls that were build in debug configuration. Try building your dlls in Release configuration (in visual studio, it's under Build > Configuration Manager) if you don't want the .pdb files. This [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241903.aspx) has more information.

Comment: .pdb files are built for Release configurations also (by default). They do not need to be deployed, however they can be useful for debugging release code.